# not able to mount filesystem (sshfs) using crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, sshfs

I have sh script file which works properly when running from command line using -

```
./start.sh
```

which starts a tomcat server and mounts a drive with sshfs

But when i do

```
crontab -e

@reboot /home/start.sh
```

then only apache tomcat starts, the sshfs does not mount, the start.sh file being -

```
/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.71/bin/startup.sh
sleep 20s
sshfs -o password_stdin,allow_other root@110.240.144.89:/home/hdd/ /home/hdd/ <<< 'password'
```

[this question at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453302/not-able-to-mount-filesystem-sshfs-using-crontab)

Comment: Are you sure that the script is not waiting for tomcat to terminate?

Comment: tomcat starts in a seperate thread and ends the caller instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the answer in the post
[Mounting fuse sshfs fails when invoked by Cron on FreeBSD 9.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/430669/mounting-fuse-sshfs-fails-when-invoked-by-cron-on-freebsd-9-0) :

> It turns out the $PATH environment variable was the cause of this
> issue. Modified the script above set the PATH identically to the
> shell, and now it works without issue:
>
> ```
>  PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/‌​root/bin"
>
>  export PATH
> ```
>
> I guess the lesson is never to make any assumptions about the minimal
> Cron environment.

Comment: askubuntu are saying herestrings <<< are not supported by cron so would have to try with systemd - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453302/not-able-to-mount-filesystem-sshfs-using-crontab

Comment: Bash certainly supports herestrings.

Comment: bash does it as in the question it does run but not from cron, its working now with systemd see the answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453302/not-able-to-mount-filesystem-sshfs-using-crontab

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya: The difference isn't cron; the difference is that the script that's being run from cron is missing the `#!/bin/bash` header line to _request_ bash, so it's not guaranteed to be interpreted by bash – it'll be run through whatever shell /bin/sh is.